How do I review IPv6 routing advertisements with the `ip` command?
This question is a follow-up on How can I view IPv6 router advertisements that are being received by my computer for diagnostic purposes?.
When the system already received routing advertisements and configured itself for the new routes: How can I view them as they are configured, using the ip command?

There are two possibilities for viewing ipv6 routes:
$ ip -6 route show
...
default proto ra metric 101
    nexthop via 0123::4567:890a:bcde dev enp1s0 weight 1 pref medium

or
$ ip -6 neigh
0123::4567:890a:bcde dev enp1s0 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55 router STALE

